# About VueX good mutation practice

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

With a VueX store split up in modules, is it good practice to have a mutation in one module perform changes in a state from another module ?

I have a strong feeling that it is not and that module state should be modified only by mutations from within that same module. Is that right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of an opinionated question and it's hard to be answered without any concrete use-case nor code, but it is totally fine to interact between modules. It can be done via `root`, hence if it's here, it's not an anti-pattern.

It all depends of your codebase.

https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#dispatch

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand that calling the dispatch function on another module action is fine. What I had in mind however is to directly modify the state of that other module without calling dispatch or commit. Instead of : dispatch('othermodule/function', payload, {root}) it would be sthg like that :  store.state.othermodule.moduleobject = 'Hello World!'

Comment: Oh yeah, this one is bad and should not be done. Modify the state only with a mutation.